# spring - how to set explicitly primary=false?

Tags: spring, spring-bean, spring-context

I am building a jar dependency that will create a bean of a type that is likely to exist already in the apps that will use that dependency.
I want to create a configuration spring class in the dependency to mark that bean as "secondary".
How can we set explicitly a bean as secondary `(or @Primary(value=false) )` in spring with annotations or with java config?
There is also the `autoWireCandidate` on the `@Bean` annotation. But that is available only from the very young spring versions.

Comment: do you mean optional bean?

Comment: It will not be optional per se. it will always be created. I just want to make sure it does not mess up existing beans.